# Listas de objetos de clases hijas en C#

Tags: c#, class, herencia, null

Tengo una clase abstracta con 3 clases que heredan de ella.
Mi idea es hacer una lista de objetos de diferentes clases hijas.
Cada una con su diferente constructor.
Por ejemplo:

```
abstract class Coche;
class Mercedes : Coche;
class Renault : Coche;
class Seat : Coche;

List<Coche> misCoches;
misCoches.add(new Mercedes(atributo, atributo, atributo));
misCoches.add(new Seat(atributo, atributo));
```

Al intentar añadir el primer objeto me lanza el error:
**System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**
que añade que *'misCoches'* fue **null**

Quizá no es posible hacer lo que intento? La lista debe ser exclusiva del objeto que marco al declarar la variable aunque sea abstracto?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta inicializar el objeto List<> de esta manera

```
List<Coche> misCoches = new List<Coche>();
```

Y ahora si puedes agregarle objetos

```
misCoches.add(new Mercedes(atributo, atributo, atributo));
misCoches.add(new Seat(atributo, atributo));
```

Comment: @Carlitos no vas a inicializar la clase Coche, lo que inicializaras sera la Lista, List<> Tambien es un objeto y se necesita inicializar como cualquier otro objeto

Comment: Toda la razón. Muchas gracias!